# Specifying a file path and name in mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);

Tags: android

In:

mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);

what is the format of the 'path' paramter?

E.g. My file is c:\program\files\file1.mp3. How do i specify the file name and path to the function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the SD Card of your phone:

```
String SDCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

Or do you want to get all music data files from your storage?

Comment: I am trying to do this on the emulator.

Comment: Then you should probably create a virtual device by using the SDK Manager and add a SDK card to it.
"Virtual Devices" -> "New" and specify a SD Card.

After that, you can add files to the SD Card. (better way I think, if you want to run it on the real device later)


You find the created device in "C:\Users\YourName\.android\avd\YourDeviceName.avd" There you can open the sdcard.img and add files.

Comment: I have created the AVD with SD card and can see it fle explorer when I run the new AVD. How do I copy files to it? I am using windows and mtools is referred to but I can't find it.

Comment: Well, my way was to browse to the device folder "C:\Users\YourName\.android\avd\YourDeviceName" and open the sdcard.img. I used something like MagicISO to open it and copy & paste the files into it. Don't remember actually, sorry. Maybe there's a better way. :)

Comment: found how to do the upload. An icon in DDMS. Thks.

Answer (score 0):

Get the file as a File object, and use its .getAbsolutePath() method to pass it in.
Not the only way, but it worked best for me. The format depends on if it's in internal, external, or application storage if you want to pass in the path yourself.

Comment: I am just trying to play the .mp3 on the emulator at the moment.

Comment: Is there as file location that has the same specification on the emulator and the device? If so, what would it be?